# Rotate outer matrix by n step

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix

I have a matrix like

```
matrix1 = [1,2
           3,4]

matrix2 =[1,2,3
         4,5,6
         7,8,9]
```

I want to rotate this matrix by certain step like r=1 then output would be like

```
output_matrix = [3,1
                 4,2]

output_matrix = [4,1,2
                 7,5,3
                 8,9,6]
```

how can I achieve this, rotation of step would be dynamic.

I found this solution, but this is for fixed rotation ie. step=1

```
def rotateMatrix(mat):

    if not len(mat):
        return

    top = 0
    bottom = len(mat)-1

    left = 0
    right = len(mat[0])-1

    while left < right and top < bottom:

        # Store the first element of next row,
        # this element will replace first element of
        # current row
        prev = mat[top+1][left]

        # Move elements of top row one step right
        for i in range(left, right+1):
            curr = mat[top][i]
            mat[top][i] = prev
            prev = curr

        top += 1

        # Move elements of rightmost column one step downwards
        for i in range(top, bottom+1):
            curr = mat[i][right]
            mat[i][right] = prev
            prev = curr

        right -= 1

        # Move elements of bottom row one step left
        for i in range(right, left-1, -1):
            curr = mat[bottom][i]
            mat[bottom][i] = prev
            prev = curr

        bottom -= 1

        # Move elements of leftmost column one step upwards
        for i in range(bottom, top-1, -1):
            curr = mat[i][left]
            mat[i][left] = prev
            prev = curr

        left += 1

    return mat


matrix =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

matrix = rotateMatrix(matrix)
# # Print modified matrix
print(matrix)
```

Comment: why don't you call your rotation matrix several times to achieve what you want?

Comment: I can, but that would be not a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotate(r,matrix):
        '''for rotating the values on the outer ring of a matrix of size HxW'''
        height = len(matrix)
        width = len(matrix[0])
        matrixMap = mapMatrix(height,width)
        r %= len(matrixMap)
        rotatedMap = matrixMap[-r:]+matrixMap[:-r]
        newMatrix = {el:matrix[el[0]][el[1]] for el in matrixMap}
        for i,el in enumerate(rotatedMap):
            matrix[matrixMap[i][0]][matrixMap[i][1]] = newMatrix[el]
        return matrix

def mapMatrix(h,w):
        matrix = []
        for i in range(w):
            matrix.append((0,i))
        for i in range(1,h):
            matrix.append((i,w-1))
        for i in range(w-2,-1,-1):
            matrix.append((h-1,i))
        for i in range(h-2,0,-1):
            matrix.append((i,0))
        return matrix
```

This is how I would implement it, but I think there is still some room for improvement. Supports negative r. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine rotate and transpose to get what you want

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], int)
m1 = np.rot90(m)
m2 = m1.transpose()
print (m2)
```

This will give you

```
[[2 1]
 [4 3]]
```

Change however you wish.

Actually you can choose elements like this

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], int)
# create tuple
new = (m[0][1],m[1][0])
# print list
print (list(new))

[2, 3]
```

Comment: can we not do it without using any package, I am looking solution without using any lib.

Comment: Do you actually get their matrix2 example correct? I doubt it.

Comment: Stefan Pochmann is correct this solution does not work for 3*3 matrices.

Comment: yes Steven is right,but for example SVD could help in his case.He mentioned he does nto want any package.